# How to except some rows for vba code in MS project

Tags: vba, ms-project

I already wrote code for update predecessor in task and it worked. 
*For example* New task which consist of wire cut, edm and cmm process it can update predecessor automatically. But just for some task I don't want to update predecessor.
I Want to add this **except for unique id =2,3** Where should I add in my code.
This is my code

```
Sub AutoPredecessorRepairLevel3()

    Dim TA As Task
    Dim TB As Task

    For Each TA In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If (TA.Name Like "*report*") Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*fitting*") Or (TB.Name Like "*cmm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*polishing*") Or (TB.Name Like "*edm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TB.Name Like "*milling el*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

        If (TA.Name Like "*fitting*") Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*cmm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*polishing*") Or (TB.Name Like "*edm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TB.Name Like "*milling el*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

        If (TA.Name Like "*cmm*") Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*polishing*") Or (TB.Name Like "*edm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TB.Name Like "*milling el*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

        If (TA.Name Like "*polishing*") Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*edm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TB.Name Like "*milling el*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

        If (TA.Name Like "*edm*") Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TB.Name Like "*milling el*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

        If (TA.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TA.Name Like "*milling el*") Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*el design*") Or (TB.Name Like "*design el*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

        If (TA.Name Like "*wire cut*") And Not TA.Name = "cam wire cut" Then
        For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
            If (TB.Name Like "*cam wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*cam wire*") Then
            TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
            End If
        Next TB
        End If

    Next TA
```

Comment: Not really sure what you are asking here... but you can use `Not` also... `If Not (TA.Name Like "*report*") Then` to do the opposite. You could also use a `Select Case` to do similar things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Not (TA.UniqueID = 2 Or TA.UniqueID = 3)` along with your other tests to skip over tasks with UniqueID = 2 or 3:

```
Sub AutoPredecessorRepairLevel3()

    Dim TA As Task
    Dim TB As Task

    For Each TA In ActiveProject.Tasks
        If Not (TA.UniqueID = 2 Or TA.UniqueID = 3) And (TA.Name Like "*report*") Then
            For Each TB In TA.OutlineParent.OutlineChildren
                If Not (TB.UniqueID = 2 Or TB.UniqueID = 3) And ((TB.Name Like "*fitting*") Or (TB.Name Like "*cmm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*polishing*") Or (TB.Name Like "*edm*") Or (TB.Name Like "*wire cut*") Or (TB.Name Like "*el milling*") Or (TB.Name Like "*milling el*")) Then
                    TA.LinkPredecessors Tasks:=TB
                End If
            Next TB
        End If

        '....

    Next TA

End Sub
```